# Launch another midlet from midlet

Tags: java-me, push, midp, launch, midlet

I made the program Test.jar which there is a menu to run another program (Hello.jar). 
I've been looking for and get the following code

```
callLauncher("javaapp:midlet-name=Hello;midlet-vendor=Vendor");
```

and

```
PushRegistry.registerAlarm("Hello",now.getTime()+100);
```

but not successful - throws `ClassNotFoundException`. Is there another way?

Comment: does [registerAlarm](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/io/PushRegistry.html#registerAlarm(java.lang.String,%20long)) return any value or throw an exception?

Comment: throw an ClassNotFoundException..  :(
it should be in a Midlet suite?

Test application and Hello application is a different project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[API documentation for the method you use (registerAlarm)](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/io/PushRegistry.html#registerAlarm%28java.lang.String,%20long%29) explains pretty clearly what you did wrong:

> **Throws:**
>   ...`ClassNotFoundException` - if the MIDlet class name can not be found in the current MIDlet suite or if this class is not included in any of the MIDlet-<n> records in the descriptor file or the jar file manifest or if the `midlet` argument is `null`

Comment: so Test application and Hello application must be in a MIDlet suite?

can not be in a different midlet?

Comment: @And1Siahaan per my reading of API docs, MIDlet can be different but it has to be in same suite

Comment: so can not be in different suite?

Comment: @And1Siahaan as far as I can tell it can not be in different suite. Though you'd better study API docs yourself if you want to be 100% sure about that

Comment: @And1Siahaan you're welcome. By the way you can also take a look at an "instruction" explaining how we at Stack Overflow deal with _helpful_ answers: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235